# Kubernetes OpenShift for python

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift

I am new to openshift, we are trying to deploy a python module in a pod which is accessed by other python code running in different pods. When i was deploying, the pod is running and immediately crash with status **"Crash Loop Back Off"**.This python code is an independent module which does not have valid entrypoint. So how to deploy those type of python modules in openshift. Appreciate for any solutions

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You deploy something that can run as a process, and as such, has a capability to contact with the external world in some way (ie. listen for requests, connect to message broker, send requests, read/write to db etc.) you do not package and deploy libraries that on their own are inoperable to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks Radek for the reply. This python module(For E.g, Module c)  is an utility module which is accessed by different python Modules (For E.g, Module A and Module B). Module A and Module B is running in different pods. Cant I run Module C in another different POD ??. Should I package Module C along with Module A and Module B separately??